# OutputCache key format in ASP.NET MVC controller action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

What is the exact key format for the outputcache on a controller action?

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "Games")]
public virtual ActionResult EventGames(int? id, string slug)
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking - what do you mean by _exact key format_?

Comment: Each cache entry has a key, what does MVCs format look like for OutputCache?

Comment: Still not sure what you mean by _each cache entry has a key_. Are you referring to the `CacheProfile` property where `"Games"` is the key, which in turn refers to a specific item in the `<outputCacheProfiles>` section of your `web.config` file

Comment: Or are you referring to the internal mechanism where a unique identifier is given to items stored in the cache

Comment: Yes, the unique key stored for this request.  I mean if you know caching you know it has a key and outputcache has a specific key that stores the response.  I want to know this format, or the code on how it works?

Comment: Its a hashed value (generated based on a number of different values including descriptor id's of the `OutputCache` properties). Its complex, but you can inspect the source code for[OutputCacheAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs#L158) and [DescriptorUtil](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DescriptorUtil.cs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't think of any case that you need to use the OutputCache key.

Anyway, the key is generated using the following factors:
- The key prefix, predefined by OutputCacheAttribute class.
- Controller Action's uniqueId.
- VaryByCustom parameter.
- VaryByParam parameter.

Those factors will be concatenated and then hashed using **SHA256Cng**

Detail implementation can be found here: [OutputCacheAttribute.cs](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/OutputCacheAttribute.cs)

Comment: I wasnted to replicate what they were doing but with my own type of twist so I wanted to make sure it was somewhat similar.  I believe your answer is the best for this.

Answer (score -2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Add in web.config caching section

```
<caching>
   <outputCacheSettings>
      <outputCacheProfiles>
         <add name="Cache1Hour" duration="3600" varyByParam="none"/>
     </outputCacheProfiles>
  </outputCacheSettings>
</caching>
```

Then add caching profile on ActionResult

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
  public class ProfileController : Controller
  {
    [OutputCache(CacheProfile="Cache1Hour")]
    public string Index()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what this answer is